# How come declaring something as a double data type would lead the ide to think it is a integer?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, double

I am very confused on how a declared double data type would lead to the intellij ide to believe I was requiring a int to declare. Can someone give me some insight on this?

Here is the code in a picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTXPT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Double Data type :***

The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its value range is unlimited. The double data type is generally used for decimal values just like float. The double data type also should never be used for precise values, such as currency. Its default value is 0.0d.

Example: double d1 = 12.3

`Double[] yu=new Double[cholo]`

you are trying to declare an array of size double which can be floating, so you should declare an `integer in the []`, As it indicates the number of the element you want to store of type `double`.

Answer (score 0):

The value inside the square brackets is for defining the length of the array, therefore it needs an int.
If you want cholo to be in the array then use

```
double[] yu = new double[] {cholo};
```

Comment: Thank you so much but why does length have to be a integer? The length could be 25.192 inch of something so why does length have to be a interger?

Comment: Overall it's defined that way in 15.10.1 of the Java syntax standard.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf  The length of an array has to be a whole number without decimal places.  Doubles require more memory than ints.

Answer (score 0):

You have pass the size of the double array which is integer, that's why you're getting that error. 
This is the shortcut syntax to create and initialize an array of double

```
double[] values = {1,2,3,4,};
```

Comment: But I declared the double array integer to be a double so why is it a integer?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by double array integer. In the pic I see double as the type of array.